# One IBOutlet for two UILabels

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I have two views within one .xib (one view for landscape, another for portrait). How can I use the same IBOutlet I've defined in @interface section for both labels if they have the same functionality.  (ctrl+dragging to both of them does'n help-each time I drag to second, the first one loses its outlet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. IBOutlet is an (UILabel?) object that must store reference to UI element. Naturally single object cannot reference to two different objects.

Comment: Did anybody come up with a better answer for how to do this, I'm having the same issue with outlets.

Comment: @AlanMoore, you can use IBOutletCollection that can store a bunch of UI objects of the same class

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of-course you can do this using `IBOutletCollection` instead of `IBOutlet`.

```
IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *labels;
```

Use the array to access all labels at runtime.